# Using both naive and timezone aware datetimes in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

The Django docs are pretty clear that naive datetimes should not be used, but I have a use case that I imagine is fairly common where I think I need them.  Sometimes it is necessary in my project to query for objects across timezones, but based on local times.

For example, and this is just a contrived example, let's say I want to find all users who last updated their profile between 4 and 5 PM on a given day, *according each user's local timezone*.  I could simply do this as:

```
qs = User.objects.filter(profile__datelastupdated__gte=datetime(2013,4,1,16))
qs = qs.filter(profile__datelastupdated__lte=datetime(2013,4,1,17))
```

However, because I have timezone support active this causes the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) while time zone support is active.
```

I understand why the warning is getting thrown, so my question is: am I not thinking about datetimes the right way?  Is there an idomatic Django way to have the specificity of tz aware datetimes when that's what you want, and also have the desired genericness that is sometimes needed that is provided by naive datetimes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter for database with datetime + timezone all of dates in database are stored as utc always. If you provide date without time zone django treat it default like utc and gives you warring.
If you support timezones you have to store user timezone. 
Ask database with date + current user time zone the same with putting date.